# Is It Correct for global variable state in cache

Tags: oracle, plsql, global-variables, package

Is the Following Info in image about Global variable in Package is correct,if not then please tell me why.

```
Examine this code: 
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE comm_package
IS
g_comm NUMBER := 10;
PROCEDURE reset_comm(p_comm IN NUMBER);
END comm_package;
/
User Jones executes the following code at 9:01am:
EXECUTE comm_package.g_comm := 15
User Smith executes the following code at 9:05am:
EXECUTE comm_package.g_comm := 20

Which statement is True?

A.  g_comm has value of 15 at 9:06 for smith.
B.  g_comm has value of 15 at 9:06 for jones.
C.  g_comm has value of 20 at 9:06 for both smith and jones.
D.  g_comm has value of 15 at 9:03 for both smith and jones.
E.  g_comm has value of 10 at 9:06 for both smith and jones.
F.  g_comm has value of 10 at 9:03 for both smith and jones.

ANSWER: B.
```

Comment: Images can't be indexed/searched by other users, so it just 'pollutes' the question database.

Comment: THANKS ALOT For making me realize my mistake,I take care of it next time.

Answer (score 4):

Package variable state is scoped at the *session* level.  So the only user who can see `G_COMM=15` will be Jones.  Hence B is the right answer.

Comment: +1. If you need a 'cross-session' variable, look at global application context